# Multiple navbar background positions

Tags: html, css

> I'm having a problem with moving my 3 images to the same line and in order. I have managed to get the Navbar and singing into the correct passion, but whats happing is when I try to add the 3ed image it moves it to the second line. I though it was the image size that was causing it but I changed them all down to 50px / 50px and still had the problem.

Current Problem

[image]

Login / info image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcTJy.png]

center navbar image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErLi.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErLi.png]

What I want to achieve [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKJc.jpg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKJc.jpg]

I'm still new to CSS and HTML, so if u have any tips on cleaning up my code or any tricks i can use please let me know!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.mini.css">
</head>


<body>
<img src="" class="banner">

<div class="topnav">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Forums</a>
    <a href="#news">Help</a>
    <a href="#contact">store</a>
    <a href="#about">contact</a>
    </div>

     <div class="infobg">
     <div class="info">
     <a href="#about">info</a>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="loginbg">
     <div class="login">
     <a href="#about">singin</a>
     </div>
        </div>

      </body>

      </html>

 body {
 background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 /*Center Navbar*/
 .topnav {
   display: block;
   left: -50px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 200px;
   line-height: 200px;
   background-image:url(images/nav.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   background-size:100%;
   position: relative;
 }

 /*Center Navbar text postion*/
 .topnav .nav {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   width: 80%;
 }

 /*Center Navbar text style*/
 .topnav .nav a  {
   line-height: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
   width: 24%;
 }

 /*right login Navbar*/
 .loginbg {
   display: block;
   left: 650px;
   margin: 2px auto;
   width: 900px;
   height: 200px;
   line-height: 200px;
   background-image:url(images/login.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   background-size:100%;
   position: relative;
 }

 /*right login navbar text postion*/
 .login {
   position: absolute;
   left: 425px;
   width: 80%;
 }

 /*right login navbar text style*/
 .loginbg .login a  {
   line-height: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
   width: 24%;
 }

 /*left info Navbar*/
 .infobg {
    display:inline;
   display: block;
   left: 800px;
   margin: 2px auto;
   width: 900px;
   height: 200px;
   line-height: 200px;
   background-image:url(images/login.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   background-size:100%;
   position: relative;
 }

 /*left info navbar text postion*/
 .info {
   position: absolute;
   left: 425px;
   width: 80%;
 }

 /*left info navbar text style*/
 .infobg .info a  {
   line-height: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
   width: 24%;
 }

 .navbackground {
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 700px;
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
 }

 .banner {
 display: inline;   
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: auto;
   width: 100%;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to change the approach to the problem slightly.
This answer assumes you cannot change the source order of the markup, the best solution would be to move the info link before the topnav.

With this markup you can use flexbox order to change the order of the items.

```
.topnav {
    position: fixed;
    /* set this percentage to what you want but be aware of device 
    widths */
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
```

So on the two children you can then use the order property

```
.info {
   order: -1;
}
.login {
    order: 2;
}
```

There are a lot of conflicting properties in the styles you wrote, so to demonstrate what I mean here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/ZoeZxg

SIDENOTE: I also notice you are already loading bootstrap, you may find it much easier to write this using the bootstrap grid classes